# Default .htaccess file for ror that works

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What should my .htaccess file include in order to work in rails this is what I have now and I want to make sure its correct:

AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one that I used that worked. Just incase any one else needs one that works for ruby on rails with fcgi(FastCGI)

AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a new temporary rails application skeleton using the `rails` command and compare your existing `.htaccess` file to the new `.htaccess` file generated there.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make sure that something is correct is to test it operationally.  Just sayin'.

Comment: Your right but the errors that I'm getting im not sure if they are from the .htaccess file being incorrect or some other issue. I've looked every where for a default .htaccess file for ruby and I can't find one. Why not have it on stackoverflow. For other people like myself to find. Just sayin'. :)

Comment: You should probably ask about the errors you're getting rather than asking us to analyze your system components in a vacuum. :)